# change php array to look like jquery array(google charts)

Tags: php, jquery

```
['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average']
```

that's first table required to build google chart `Combo Chart`

im looking for any way to easy create it in my template i can use `implode()` but dont want to. When i pass array directly it look like this :

```
[Jack][Daniel][Poul]
```

is there a easy way to achive what google require ??

Comment: Use `json_encode($array);`.

Comment: Just split the string to get a javascript array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to send JSON.  As long as you have a current version of PHP (I believe 5.2+), you can use

```
json_encode($yourArray);
```